# Can I select output parameters using SUM from previous query with T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure, that's like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MySproc
    @Total INT OUT
AS BEGIN
    SELECT x.Column, x.Column2, SUM(x.Column) <-- I want this as an output parameter 
    FROM (
      SELECT
          Column, Column2, etc
    ) AS x

SELECT @Total = SUM(x.Column) -- Could not be bound
```

So I want to return an output parameter, and I know that I can't do it the way I have it above. I'm seeing other questions similar, but I need this as an output parameter. Also, I thought about using a temp table to store the values in and querying against that, but I'm questioning performance or if there's a better way.

I also need to return both the output parameters and result set to the client.

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to either store the entire result set in a temp table or variable, or do the query two times. There is no way in T-SQL to return a result set and do a computation on the side without making that part of the result set. It would be even better to have the client compute this result, as it's redundant from the data returned. If the client doesn't *want* the whole result on occasion (but only the sum) split the logic into two sprocs. You can share logic between those through a table-valued function or view ([and other ways](http://sommarskog.se/share_data.html)).

Comment: @JeroenMostert The client... I should have thought about this. A bit of JavaScript and it's done.

Comment: I ended up not calculating on the client, but rather went ahead and stored the results in a table variable, and queried from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more note, my real query is quite expensive, including a lot of UDFs to generate column values. Is there a better way without essentially duplicating the query?

Why are you duplicating expensive stuff that is not used?
Sum(x.column) only requires x.column.

An alternative would be to direct the query results to a #temp or table variable.

And why a derived table (x) like that.  The x.Sort DESC is not going to be able to use an index on the real sort unless the query optimizer gets very smart.

Comment: Because in my real code I have multiple output parameters, and the functions that generate the values for the x.Columns are what's expensive.

Comment: I wouldn't. The only duplication is on the columns needed, and i needed them as output parameters, else I would have just done it within the one query.

Comment: But those handful of columns are generated from expensive functions.

Comment: Then fix the question.  SELECT x.Column  - SUM(x.Column) - an output parameter

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with the question. The SUM was purposed for an output parameter, not within the result set.

Comment: What part of a separate query to sum(x.column) would not require other (expensive) columns is not clear?  An is one.  SUM(x.Column) is one.  @Total INT OUT is one.

Comment: Okay I'll edit it again momentarily. I was going to switch to client-side calculations, but I think your alternative suggestion might be the best... as in a temp table or table variable. Playing around with it now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MySproc
  @Total INT OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @Total = SUM(x.Column) 
    FROM (
       SELECT
          Column, Column2, etc
       ) AS x
  --  ORDER BY x.Sort DESC  --<-- Not required
END
```

**Edit**

Since now you have mentioned that you need to return the result set and as well as the output parameter. You will need to run the query twice.

You cannot assign value to a variable from a select query as also return results.

You can either have a select query which assign values to multiple of single variable or a query with returns a result set.

Keeping all this in mind you would re-write your proc something like this....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MySproc
  @Total INT OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- populate output variable 
    SELECT @Total = SUM(x.Column) 
    FROM (
       SELECT
          Column, Column2, etc
       ) AS x
  --  ORDER BY x.Sort DESC  --<-- Not required

-- Query for result set 
    SELECT *
    FROM (
       SELECT
          Column, Column2, etc
       ) AS x
  ORDER BY x.Sort DESC  
END
```

Comment: One more note, my real query is quite expensive, including a lot of UDFs to generate column values. Is there a better way without essentially duplicating the query?